# Track functions name, when started and when finished

Tags: r

I am trying to track name, start and end of a function. That is, when a function execute, I try to get the name of the function, when start and when finished. I use two functions, "on.exit()" and "match.call()". They are work perfectly.

```
abcde<-function(){
  cat(paste("\n function started:",match.call(),"\n ",Sys.time(),"\n"))
  on.exit({
    cat(paste("\n function finished:",match.call(),"\n ",Sys.time(),"\n"))
   })
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
abcde()
```

I am trying to make a function to do this(since I have too many functions):

```
mf_on_exit_start<-function(match_call=match.call()){
  cat(paste("\n function started:",match_call,"\n ",Sys.time(),"\n"))
  on.exit({
    cat(paste("\n function finished:",match_call,"\n ",Sys.time(),"\n"))
  })
}
abcdef<-function(){
  mf_on_exit_start(match.call())
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
abcdef()
```

But unfortunately the function does not work!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach would need your `mf_on_exit_start` to set `on.exit` within its caller (i.e. in `abcdef()`), but that's not possible.  `on.exit` always applies in the current function only.

To do what you want, you'll need to reorganize things, so that the `on.exit` happens in the caller of `abcdef()`.  For example,

```r
with_mf <- function(expr) {
  call <- deparse(substitute(expr))
  cat(paste("\n function started:",call,"\n ",Sys.time(),"\n"))
  on.exit({
    cat(paste("\n function finished:",call,"\n ",Sys.time(),"\n"))
  })
  expr
}

abcdef<-function(){
  Sys.sleep(2)
}

with_mf(abcdef())
#> 
#>  function started: abcdef() 
#>   2022-07-16 05:07:27 
#> 
#>  function finished: abcdef() 
#>   2022-07-16 05:07:29
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using a decorator function.

```
counter<-function(fn){
  force(fn)
  cnt<-0
  inner <- function(...){
    cnt <<- cnt+1
    message(sprintf("Function %s was called %s times",
                    as.character(match.call()[[1]]), cnt))
    message(paste("\n function started:",match.call()[[1]],"\n ",Sys.time(),"\n"))
    on.exit({
      message(paste("\n function finished:",match.call()[[1]],"\n ",Sys.time(),"\n"))
      
    })
    return(fn(...))
  }
  return(inner)
  
}

add<-function(a,b){
  Sys.sleep(3)
  return(a+b)
}
add<-counter(add)
add(1,2)
Function add was called 1 times

function started: add 
2022-09-25 20:21:12 


function finished: add 
2022-09-25 20:21:15 

[1] 3
add(2,6)
Function add was called 2 times

function started: add 
2022-09-25 20:21:15 


function finished: add 
2022-09-25 20:21:18 

[1] 8
mult<-function(a,b) {
  Sys.sleep(2)
  return(a*b)
}
mult<-counter(mult)
mult(2,6)
Function mult was called 1 times

function started: mult 
2022-09-25 20:21:18 


function finished: mult 
2022-09-25 20:21:20 

[1] 12
```

We essentially modified the 'add' function(or mult function) by wrapping it inside another function that added some functionality to it. We say that we decorated the function 'add' with the function 'counter' and we call the 'counter' function a decorator function.

**Decorators**

In general a decorator function:

- takes a fucntion as an argument
- return a closure
- the closure usally accepts some parameters
- runs some code in the inner function(closure) and this couse adding some functionality to original function
- the closure function calls the original function using the arguments passed to the closure
- return whatever is returned by that function call
  [image]
  Another example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73845867/closures-in-r-like-python)