# Closures in R like Python

Tags: r

First consider the following Python code that count how many times a function was called:

```
def counter(fn):
    count = 0
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal count
        count +=1
        print('Function {0} was called {1} times'.format(fn.__name__, count))
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

def add(a,b):
    return a+b
def mult(a,b):
    return a*b
add = counter(add)
mult = counter(mult)
add(1,2)
add(2,3)
mult(1,5)
#output
Function add was called 1 times
Function add was called 2 times
Function mult was called 1 times
```

Now I am trying to do the same method in R as follows:

```
counter <- function(fn) {
  cnt <- 0
  inner <- function(...) {
    cnt <<- cnt + 1
    print(paste("Function", match.call(), "was called", cnt, "times\n"))
    return(fn(...))
  }
  return(inner)
  
}
add <- function(a, b) a + b
mult <- function(a, b) a*b
cnt_add <- counter(add)
cnt_add(1, 4) 
cnt_add(3, 9)
[1] "Function cnt_add was called 1 times\n"
[2] "Function 1 was called 1 times\n"   #<---- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!  L1  
[3] "Function 4 was called 1 times\n"   #<---- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!  L2 
[1] 5
[1] "Function cnt_add was called 2 times\n"
[2] "Function 3 was called 2 times\n"   #<---- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!  L3 
[3] "Function 9 was called 2 times\n"   #<---- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!   
[1] 12
cnt_mult<-counter(mult)
cnt_mult(1,6) 
[1] "Function cnt_mult was called 1 times\n"
[2] "Function 1 was called 1 times\n"   #<---- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!  L4  
[3] "Function 6 was called 1 times\n"   #<---- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!  L5  
[1] 6
```

**a)** I expected "Function ? was called ? times\n" but why L1,L2,L3,L4,L5 printed?

**b)** When I try to (like in python)

```
add <- counter(add)
add(3, 4)
```

I get an error:   **Error: evaluation nested too deeply....**

**c)**
To avoid error in **b** I tried as follows but still got an error

```
cnt_add <- counter(add)
add <- cnt_add
add(6, 8)
```

I find out if I call cnt_add function one time no error(except additional two lines in console) happen:

```
cnt_add <- counter(add)
cnt_add(1, 8)
[1] "Function cnt_add was called 1 times\n"
[2] "Function 1 was called 1 times\n"      
[3] "Function 8 was called 1 times\n"      
[1] 9
add <- cnt_add
add(6, 8)
[1] "Function add was called 2 times\n" "Function 6 was called 2 times\n"  
[3] "Function 8 was called 2 times\n"  
[1] 14
```

But why "Function add was called 2 times", I called it one times! Why it needs at least one time call to works?

How to fix these problems? I do not want other ways since this is just a practice in closures.

Comment: Rolled back an edit because if you're commenting on an answer it should be added to the answer as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) `match.call` gives you the whole call, not just the name of the function you called.  Use `match.call()[[1]]` to get that.  But `deparse(substitute(fn))` gives you a string version of what you passed as `fn`, so it's probably better.  (My choice gives the original function name, not the modified one.  Stick with `match.call()[[1]]` if you want the modified one.)

b) You are being bitten by lazy evaluation.  Call `force(fn)` in your definition of `counter`.  The issue is that `counter` never evaluates `fn`, so it is left as a promise until it is needed the first time you call `add`.  But at that point, the definition of `add` has changed, so you get the infinite loop.  Using `force(fn)` forces the value of the promise to be determined.

```r
counter<-function(fn){
  force(fn)
  name <- deparse(substitute(fn))
  cnt <- 0
  inner <- function(...){
    cnt <<- cnt+1
    print(paste("Function",name,"was called",cnt,"times\n"))
    return(fn(...))
  }
  return(inner)
  
}
add  <- function(a,b) a+b
mult <- function(a,b) a*b
add  <-counter(add)
add(1,4)
#> [1] "Function add was called 1 times\n"
#> [1] 5
add(3,9)
#> [1] "Function add was called 2 times\n"
#> [1] 12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using `sprintf` it's more similar. `message` might better suite the kind of output. Credits for `match.call()[[1]]` to *@user2554330*, I wrapped an `as.character()` around it.

```
counter <- function(fn) {
  cnt <- 0
  inner <- function(...) {
    cnt <<- cnt + 1
    message(sprintf("Function %s was called %s times", as.character(match.call()[[1]]), cnt))
    return(fn(...))
  }
  return(inner)
}

add <- function(a, b) a + b
mult <- function(a, b) a*b
cnt_add <- counter(add)

cnt_add(1, 4)
# Function cnt_add was called 1 times 
# [1] 5

cnt_add(3, 9)
# Function cnt_add was called 3 times
# [1] 12
```

Comment: This doesn't address part b) of the question.  The issue is that nothing in `counter` evaluates `fn`, so it's only the first time you call `cnt_add` that it gets evaluated.  But if you had named that `add` as in b), you'd be using the wrong function.

Comment: @user2554330 Use `force(fn)` and `deparse(substitute))` as described in user2554330's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73845909/6574038). Take `message(sprintf(.))` from mine :)

Answer (score 1):

`fname` stores the function name. `get(fname, mode="function")` finds the function passed to `counter`.

```
counter = function(fn) {
  i = 0
  fname = deparse(substitute(fn))
  fn = get(fname, mode="function")
  function(...) {
    i <<- i+1
    cat(sprintf("Function %s was called %d times", fname, i), "\n")
    return(fn(...))
  }
}


add = function(a, b) a+b
add = counter(add)
add(1, 6)
Function add was called 1 times 
[1] 7
add(7, 6)
Function add was called 2 times 
[1] 13
 
mult = function(a, b) a*b
mult = counter(mult)
mult(2, 3)
Function mult was called 1 times 
[1] 6
mult(5, 3)
Function mult was called 2 times 
[1] 15
```

Comment: This won't work if an expression is passed as `fn`, e.g. `add <- counter(function(a, b) a + b)`.  You should let R evaluate `fn`, you shouldn't use `get()`.